# Why does this VBScript run fine in Excel VBA but as a stand alone vbscript?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, vbscript, scripting

I wrote this VBscript to create a zip file and then copy a folder into it. When I run the script as a Sub in excel it creates the file and copys the folder into it perfectly but when I run it as a .vbs file it creates the zip file and nothing else happens. I tried adding wscript.sleep 10000 after the zip file is created but before the it copies the files and still nothing happens. I also tried using FileExists to check if the zip file exists before the copy and it returns true but still won't copy. Here is the code.

```
Dim dtmValu
dtmValue = Now()
Dim DestPath
DestPath = "C:\Users\FirstUser\Desktop\Test\" & Month(dtmValue) & "_" & Day(dtmValue) & "_" & Year(dtmValue) & ".zip"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(DestPath, 8, vbTrue)
BlankZip = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6)
For x = 0 To 17
BlankZip = BlankZip & Chr(0)
Next
ts.Write BlankZip
        Set objFolder = Nothing
        Set objShell = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set ts = Nothing
 
 
Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.Application")
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(DestPath)
Dim sFolder
sFolder = "C:\Users\FirstUser\Desktop\TestSource\"
objFolder.CopyHere (oFso.GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder))
```

Comment: I mean, the smartass answer to this is vba <> vbscript

Comment: Not sure it would fix the problem, but I'm guessing you don't need the extra parentheses in the last line: `objFolder.CopyHere oFso.GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)`.

Comment: I tried removing the extra parenthesis and there was no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line: `objFolder.CopyHere (oFso.GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder))` Executes async and presumably your `objFolder` is being destroyed before it can finish the operation.

Try adding some logic to check that the copy completes before exiting the script. You mentioned you added a wait, but its hard to say if that is long enough and many factors could make the time vary. But this approach should be a bit more stable. Take a count of items before the copy, then compare the count after and don't let it end until the copy completes:

```
'// your pre-copy code here:
'//...

Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.Application")
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(DestPath)
cnt = objFolder.Items.Count + 1 '// I added this
Dim sFolder

objFolder.CopyHere oFso.GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder) 

'// and this
While objFolder.Items.Count < cnt
    WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Since it ran fine VBA I guess the copyhere method doesn't execute asynchronously in when done in the VBA editor?